# Sublime text 3 asks me to choose a default language whenever I open it

Tags: windows, windows-10, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Sublime text 3 asks me to choose a default language whenever I open it. I have the latest version, installed on windows 10. Each time I open sublime I see this

[image]

Even if I pick english or whatever, the next time I open sublime, I will see the same dialog. I noticed that after picking english, I get another popup saying:

> Language English is checked out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this issue is related to [docphp](https://github.com/acabin/docphp/issues/4) plugin. I notified the creator of the plugin about it. Will post a fix, whenever it's fixed.